# Jasmin tests fail when run with Resharper

Tags: jasmine, resharper

When I run tests with Chutzpah everything is ok.
But when I start them with Resharper in a browser I get the following error:

`TypeError: jasmine.addMatchers is not a function`

and for PhantomJS:

`TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers)')`

Cannot find the reason of this oddity.

Code of the test:

```
describe('Directive: alert', function () {
    var scope, compile;
    var element;

    beforeEach(function () {
        jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers); // from jasmine-wu-test-library.js

        module('serviceRequestModule');
        inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            compile = $compile;
        });

        element = angular.element(
            '<div>' +
              '<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}"' +
                'close="removeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}' +
              '</alert>' +
            '</div>');

        scope.alerts = [
          { msg: 'foo', type: 'success' },
          { msg: 'bar', type: 'error' },
          { msg: 'baz' }
        ];
    });

    function createAlerts() {
        compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        return element.find('alert');
    }

    function findCloseButton(index) {
        return element.find('.close').eq(index);
    }

    function findContent(index) {
        return element.find('span').eq(index);
    }

    it('should generate alerts using ng-repeat', function () {
        var alerts = createAlerts();
        expect(alerts.length).toEqual(3);
    });
});
```